# blazor page is not loading sessionData into RadzenGrid like it should be

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, form-data, radzen

I have a form that allows users to fill out multiple fields for electronics surplus.it stores the data for all the fields that I have in a RadzenCard using browser session storage then loads the data from session storage in a grid view on the summary page (Page 2) where all the entered information can be reviewed before it is updated in the database. the issue is that its mot loading the sessionData into the RadzenGrid on the summary (page 2)

here is page 1's code:

```
@page "/form"
@using System.Text.Json;
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject DialogService DialogService
@inject ContextMenuService ContextMenuService
@inject TooltipService TooltipService
@inject NotificationService NotificationService
@inject NavigationManager NavManager


<PageTitle>Form</PageTitle>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="h3" style="display: block">Welcome Christopher DeBrodie!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <RadzenDropDownDataGrid TValue="string" ValueProperty="BuildingName" TextProperty="BuildingName" Data="@buildingLists" Placeholder="School Name" Style="width: 100%" AllowSorting="false" AllowSelectAll="false" AllowFiltering="false" ShowSearch="false" PageSize="60">
                    <Columns>
                        <RadzenDropDownDataGridColumn Property="BuildingName" Title="BuildingName" />
                    </Columns>
                </RadzenDropDownDataGrid>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                @foreach (var inputData in inputCardData)
                {
                    <div class="col-md-12"> <!-- Add this div to control card width -->
                        <RadzenCard  Variant="Radzen.Variant.Filled">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <RadzenAutoComplete TextProperty="CPSNumber" Data="@surplusItemsNews" @bind-Value="inputData.CPSNumber" Placeholder="CPS Number" Style="width: 100%" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <RadzenAutoComplete TextProperty="Description" Data="@surplusItemsNews" @bind-Value="inputData.Description" Placeholder="Item Description" Style="width: 100%" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <RadzenDropDownDataGrid TValue="string" ValueProperty="ReasonDescription" TextProperty="ReasonDescription" Data="@reasons" Style="width: 100%" ShowSearch="false" AllowFiltering="false" AllowSorting="false" AllowSelectAll="false" Placeholder="Reason For Surplus" PageSize="10">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <RadzenDropDownDataGridColumn Property="ReasonDescription" Title="ReasonDescription" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </RadzenDropDownDataGrid>
                            </div>
                        </RadzenCard>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<RadzenButton Style="width: 100%; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; height: 40px; display: block; background-color: #005570" Text="Review" Click="FinalizeList"></RadzenButton>

@code {
    [Inject]
    protected Surplus.WASPOService WASPOService { get; set; }

    protected System.Linq.IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.SurplusItemsNew> surplusItemsNews;
    protected System.Linq.IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.BuildingList> buildingLists;
    protected System.Linq.IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.Reason> reasons;

    // Create a class to hold form data
    public class FormData
    {
        public string CPSNumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ReasonDescription { get; set; }
    }

// Create a list to store instances of the form data
    List<FormData> inputCardData = new List<FormData>(){ new FormData () };


    // Function to save inputCardData to session storage
    private async Task SaveInputCardDataToSessionStorage()
    {
        try
        {
            var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(inputCardData);
            await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("sessionStorage.setItem", "inputCardData", json);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error saving to session storage: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    // Function to load inputCardData from session storage
    private async Task LoadInputCardDataFromSessionStorage()
    {
        try
        {
            var json = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("sessionStorage.getItem", "inputCardData");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(json))
            {
                inputCardData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<FormData>>(json);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error loading from session storage: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        surplusItemsNews = await WASPOService.GetSurplusItemsNews();
        buildingLists = await WASPOService.GetBuildingLists();
        reasons = await WASPOService.GetReasons();

        // Load inputCardData from session storage when the page initializes
        await LoadInputCardDataFromSessionStorage();
    }

    // Event handler for the "Finalize List" button
    private async Task FinalizeList()
    {
        // Save the input card data to session storage
        await SaveInputCardDataToSessionStorage();

        // Navigate to the summary page
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/summary");
    }
}
```

and here is page 2's code:

```
@page "/summary"
@using System.Text.Json;
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject DialogService DialogService
@inject ContextMenuService ContextMenuService
@inject TooltipService TooltipService
@inject NotificationService NotificationService

<PageTitle>Summary</PageTitle>

<RadzenGrid Data="@sessionData" TItem="FormData">
    <Columns>
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="FormData" Property="CPSNumber" Title="CPS Number" />
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="FormData" Property="Description" Title="Item Description" />
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="FormData" Property="ReasonDescription" Title="Reason For Surplus" />
    </Columns>
</RadzenGrid>

@code {
    // Define the FormData class if it's not already defined
    public class FormData
    {
        public string CPSNumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ReasonDescription { get; set; }
    }

    // Read the stored session data
    private List<FormData> sessionData = new List<FormData>();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Load the session data from Session Storage using IJSRuntime
        try
        {
            var storedDataJson = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("sessionStorage.getItem", "sessionData");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(storedDataJson))
            {
                sessionData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<FormData>>(storedDataJson);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error loading from Session Storage: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

I am still really new with developing in blazor so sorry if this sounds like a noob question. Any help would be amazing!!!

Comment: I may be missing something here, but I don't see anywhere in your code where you actually store data into SessionStorage.  All I can see is `var sessionData = inputCardData;`.  MS Docs provides information on how to use SessionStorage - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-7.0&pivots=server#save-and-load-data-within-a-component.  You can use the `ProtectedSessionStore` class to do most of the work for you.

Comment: thank you for the link @MrCakaShaunCurtis I tried incorporating what you sent me but the summary page is still not loading the data! I updated the question to have the updated code in it can you please look at it and let me know what I am doing wrong? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code:

```cs
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Load the session data from Session Storage using IJSRuntime
        try
        {
            var storedDataJson = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("sessionStorage.getItem", "sessionData");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(storedDataJson))
            {
                sessionData = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<FormData>>(storedDataJson);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error loading from Session Storage: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

is returning null, because when you execute it, the component has not yet rendered, so there's no access to the browser.

As you've labelled this a Server Side question, I'm assuming this is Blazor Server.

There are two options.

1. Run the code in `OnAfterRenderASync` which I'm not a fan of because you are mutating the component state and need to do a re-render to get the new state reflected in the UI.
2. Do an async yield prior to trying to get the value.  This will let the internal component lifecycle code do a render before trying to retrieve the state.  You also need to be aware of Server Pre-Rendering.

Here's an example page that uses the `ProtectedSessionStorage` class rather than raw JSInterop calls [it handles all the serialization for you], and detects server pre-rendering.  There are inline comments.

```cs
@page "/counter"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.ProtectedBrowserStorage

@inject ProtectedSessionStorage ProtectedSessionStore
@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="this.SetSessionData">Set Session Data</button>

<div>
    <pre>Session Data: @(_sessionData?.Value ?? "Not Set")</pre>
</div>

@code {
    private StorageData? _sessionData = new("-- Not Set --");

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Detect if we are doing a server side Pre Render.  If so use the default value 
        var isNotServerPreRender = HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext is not null && HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.HasStarted;

        if (isNotServerPreRender)
        {
            // Do an async Yield to let the first render happen
            await Task.Yield();

            // We can now interact with JSInterop as the component has rendered
            var result = await ProtectedSessionStore.GetAsync<StorageData>("sessionData");

            // Get the result Value which will
            _sessionData = result.Value;
        }
    }

    private async Task SetSessionData()
        => await ProtectedSessionStore.SetAsync("sessionData", new StorageData($"Set at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}"));

    public record StorageData(string Value);
}
```