# RadzenCard are not showing up when using Blazored.LocalStorage to store the items filled out in it in local storage

Tags: c#, blazor, local-storage, blazor-server-side

I have a form that allows users to fill out multiple fields for electronics surplus.it stores the data for all the fields that I have in a RadzenCard using Blazored LocalStorage then loads the data from Blazored LocalStorage in a grid view on the summary page (Page 2) where all the entered information can be reviewed before it is updated in the database. my issue is that my RadzenCard on page one is not showing up at all when I run the app. it shows everything else but not the RadzenCard. here is my code for that page:

```
@page "/form"
@using System.Text.Json;
@using Blazored.LocalStorage;
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject DialogService DialogService
@inject ContextMenuService ContextMenuService
@inject TooltipService TooltipService
@inject NotificationService NotificationService
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@inject Blazored.LocalStorage.ILocalStorageService oLocalStore


<PageTitle>Form</PageTitle>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <h1 class="h3" style="display: block">Welcome Username!</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                <RadzenDropDownDataGrid TValue="string" ValueProperty="BuildingName" TextProperty="BuildingName" Data="@buildingLists" Placeholder="School Name" Style="width: 100%" AllowSorting="false" AllowSelectAll="false" AllowFiltering="false" ShowSearch="false" PageSize="60">
                    <Columns>
                        <RadzenDropDownDataGridColumn Property="BuildingName" Title="BuildingName" />
                    </Columns>
                </RadzenDropDownDataGrid>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group">
                @foreach (var inputData in inputCardData)
                {
                    <div class="col-md-12"> <!-- Add this div to control card width -->
                        <RadzenCard  Variant="Radzen.Variant.Filled">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <RadzenAutoComplete TextProperty="CPSNumber" Data="@surplusItemsNews" @bind-Value="inputData.CPSNumber" Placeholder="CPS Number" Style="width: 100%" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <RadzenAutoComplete TextProperty="Description" Data="@surplusItemsNews" @bind-Value="inputData.Description" Placeholder="Item Description" Style="width: 100%" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <RadzenDropDownDataGrid TValue="string" ValueProperty="ReasonDescription" TextProperty="ReasonDescription" Data="@reasons" Style="width: 100%" ShowSearch="false" AllowFiltering="false" AllowSorting="false" AllowSelectAll="false" Placeholder="Reason For Surplus" PageSize="10">
                                    <Columns>
                                        <RadzenDropDownDataGridColumn Property="ReasonDescription" Title="ReasonDescription" />
                                    </Columns>
                                </RadzenDropDownDataGrid>
                            </div>
                        </RadzenCard>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


<RadzenButton Style="width: 100%; min-width: 0px; min-height: 0px; height: 40px; display: block; background-color: #005570" Text="Review" Click="FinalizeList"></RadzenButton>

@code {
    [Inject]
    protected Surplus.WASPOService WASPOService { get; set; }

    protected System.Linq.IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.SurplusItemsNew> surplusItemsNews;
    protected System.Linq.IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.BuildingList> buildingLists;
    protected System.Linq.IQueryable<Surplus.Models.WASPO.Reason> reasons;

    // Create a class to hold form data
    public class FormData
    {
        public string CPSNumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ReasonDescription { get; set; }
    }

    // Inject the ILocalStorageService
    [Inject]
    private ILocalStorageService localStorage { get; set; }

    // Create a list to store instances of the form data
    List<FormData> inputCardData;

    // Constructor to initialize inputCardData
    public Form()
    {
        inputCardData = new List<FormData>();
    }

    // Function to save inputCardData to local storage
    private async Task SaveInputCardDataToLocalStorage()
    {
        try
        {
            await localStorage.SetItemAsync("inputCardData", inputCardData);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error saving to local storage: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    // Function to load inputCardData from local storage
    private async Task LoadInputCardDataFromLocalStorage()
    {
        try
        {
            inputCardData = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<List<FormData>>("inputCardData");
            // Initialize the list if it's null
            if (inputCardData == null)
            {
                inputCardData = new List<FormData>();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error loading from local storage: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        surplusItemsNews = await WASPOService.GetSurplusItemsNews();
        buildingLists = await WASPOService.GetBuildingLists();
        reasons = await WASPOService.GetReasons();

        // Load inputCardData from local storage when the page initializes
        await LoadInputCardDataFromLocalStorage();
    }

    // Event handler for the "Finalize List" button
    private async Task FinalizeList()
    {
        // Save the input card data to local storage
        await SaveInputCardDataToLocalStorage();

        // Navigate to the summary page
        NavManager.NavigateTo("/summary");
    }
}
```

here is the code for page 2:

```
@page "/summary"
@using System.Text.Json;
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject DialogService DialogService
@inject ContextMenuService ContextMenuService
@inject TooltipService TooltipService
@inject NotificationService NotificationService
@using Blazored.LocalStorage

<PageTitle>Summary</PageTitle>

<RadzenGrid Data="@sessionData" TItem="FormData">
    <Columns>
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="FormData" Property="CPSNumber" Title="CPS Number" />
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="FormData" Property="Description" Title="Item Description" />
        <RadzenGridColumn TItem="FormData" Property="ReasonDescription" Title="Reason For Surplus" />
    </Columns>
</RadzenGrid>

@code {
    // Define the FormData class if it's not already defined
    public class FormData
    {
        public string CPSNumber { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ReasonDescription { get; set; }
    }

    // Read the stored local storage data
    private List<FormData> sessionData = new List<FormData>();

    // Inject the ILocalStorageService
    [Inject]
    private ILocalStorageService localStorage { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Load the data from local storage
        try
        {
            sessionData = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<List<FormData>>("inputCardData");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error loading from local storage: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I see when I load page 1:
[image: no card is showing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cs
List<FormData> inputCardData; 
inputCardData = new List<FormData>();
```

`new List<FormData>()` creates a List however, the list is initially empty because there is no FormData instances in it.

```html
@foreach (var inputData in inputCardData)
{
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
        <RadzenCard  Variant="Radzen.Variant.Filled">
        <!-- rest of your code -->
}
```

Your `RadzenCard` along with all the other HTML elements are inside a `foreach` loop of the list. Since the list is empty that means that there will **not** even be a single run of the loop, so everything inside that loop will be ignored.

```
private async Task LoadInputCardDataFromLocalStorage()
{
    try
    {
        inputCardData = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<List<FormData>>("inputCardData");
        // Initialize the list if it's null
        if (inputCardData == null)
        {
            inputCardData = new List<FormData>();
            //Initialize list with Default instance of FormData when nothing is stored in local storage
            FormData defaultFormData = new FormData();
            inputCardData.Add(defaultFormData);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error loading from local storage: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

That's why wherever you initialize an empty `inputCardData` list then you need to include a default FormData instance in it.

Comment: thank you so much for the help! So when you say I "need to include a default FormData instance in it" do you mean copy what I have in the RadzenCard  and put it before the foreach loop? if that's not correct can you please show me a code example as to what you are talking about? again thank you for all the help so far!!!!

Comment: look at the third code block. that's my example of what you need to do. I've added comments on it aswell.

Comment: Thank you for the updated suggestion I tried your suggestion and its still not working I added a screen shot to the original question as to what I see when I try yours and @MrC aka Shaun Curtis suggestions. any other advice on how to get this working? Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: your code example worked I just had to update visual studio 2022 to the latest version!!! thank you for all your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

On Page 1 see my inline comments on this code.

```cs
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
       // these should all yield so the page does it's first render
       // but I'm guessing these are probably sync code wrapped in a Task
       
        surplusItemsNews = await WASPOService.GetSurplusItemsNews();
        buildingLists = await WASPOService.GetBuildingLists();
        reasons = await WASPOService.GetReasons();

         // add a true yield to see what happens
         await Task.Yield();
        // Load inputCardData from local storage when the page initializes
        await LoadInputCardDataFromLocalStorage();
    }
```

And in this code on Page 2, you are trying to access the local storage before the page loads.  I'm guessing it's wrapped in a try because it throws an error.

```cs
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
         // add a true yield to see what happens
         await Task.Yield();

        // Load the data from local storage
        try
        {
            sessionData = await localStorage.GetItemAsync<List<FormData>>("inputCardData");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Error loading from local storage: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }
```

See my answer to your previous version of this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77129240/13065781

It also shows you how to use the built in `ProtectedSessionStorage`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I tried your suggestion and its still not working I added a screen shot to the original question as to what I see when I try your suggestion any other suggestions to fix this issue? thank you for all the help so far! :)

Comment: My guess is there's something important you are doing [but don't think is important] that you aren't telling us.  You need to condense your problem into a [mre] similar to what I've shown you in the previous answer to progress,

Comment: It works now I just had to update visual studio 2022 to the latest version!!! thank you for all your help!!!